# Computer A can reach network web service, while computer B can't. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, security, networking

You'll have to pardon me as I wasn't sure where to place this. This overlaps in the areas of C# Web Services and Network/Security management I suppose.

I have a server that runs various web applications. One of them is a web service. The account everything runs under is a local account on the machine. It is not a domain account. I don't know why this was done how it was, but it's one of those things that's just the way is because it's the way it was done.

Super, huh?

Okay so my domain account name is given full permissions on the web serivce. Now, while the account the web service runs under is not a domain account, the machine is on our domain and in our network. So, from my computer, I can fire up a browser and type in the url to the web service in this fashion:

http://serverhere:porthere/servicename

Now the fun part. From a different machine on the same network and logged in my domain account, I cannot load the web service.

Here is the really, really nutty part. From both machines A and B, I cannot ping the server hosting the web service. Might be because pinging is turned off.

So the million dollar question is, does any one have any idea's at all as to why computer B cannot access the web service while computer A (my machine) can?

The server hosting the web service is running windows 2000. My machine is running windows xp. The machine that cannot load the web service is running Windows 2003 SP 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot load the web service"?  Do you get an error?  Does the request time out?  What is the HTTP response code (if any)?

Comment: I just get a page that says "Internet Explorer cannot display the web page..."

Comment: More like a network config issue, not programming related.

Comment: I figured, but it is a .net web service so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Not programming related. IT Overflow is coming, but this isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the subnet masks for both machines are the same; if one subnet is more restrictive than the other, it'll basically ignore messages from that machine.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many options for this. And I would not bet on account permission issue. You should check the communication with network sniffer, like wireshark or network monitor. Check proxy settings. and post more information about the error you receive.

Answer (score 1):

Silly suggestion, but did you check the firewall settings on the 2003 machine?